# Angular: error installing devDependencies in Quickstart

Tags: angular

Angular's [5-minute quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) has the following in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
}
```

When I do `npm install`, the modules listed in the Dependencies section install without error, but I get an error (see below) when trying to install the devDependencies.

I tried to install these packages separately and noticed that I cannot `--save-dev` but can install via the global option, `-g`. That is, for the concurrently package,

```
npm install concurrently --save-dev # does NOT work, same error

npm install concurrently -g # does work
```

In fact, if I install all of the devDependencies globally, I can complete the quickstart.

This is good but would like to better understand why a `--save-dev` install fails.

I have a completely clean linux VM install with current versions of both node(v6.3.0) and npm(v3.10.3).

Thanks in advance!

Chris

### Error Message

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-92-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "concurrently" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/vagrant/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/vagrant/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/angular2-quickstart/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this as root/admin? If so, same errors?

Comment: `sudo npm install` does not work (same error) but using `sudo` on an individual package works, i.e. `sudo npm install concurrently --save-dev` works.